# Someone used my router to set up their own network

Tags: router

This may be a stupid question.     My router was unsecured for a while.   We think the neighbors set up their own network using our router, creating a new network name, new wifi and router password.

We have since secured (WPA2) our network, changed the network name, changed the password for the router and the wifi.

Here's the stupid question......can the neighbors still connect to the internet using their network that they've set up on our router?

Answer (score 3):

Okay answer: If you changed the router password and the wifi password they shouldn't be able to get in.

Better answer: I'd recommend a configuration reset on the router by using a paperclip on the tiny hole in the back (depending on your model) check for the latest firmware and set your own passwords complex passwords.

Best of luck, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I'd seriously recommend the paperclip reset....

Answer (score 2):

No, they wont be able to.  Assuming you did a hard-reset on the router (paperclip method), all of the settings should have been cleared.  The router only "broadcasts" a single network, and it's credentials are **only** the ones that you have supplied.  Outside of having a strong password, you should be fine.

As a general rule of thumb, use WPA-2 to encrypt your password.  Other popular forms such as WEP and WPA can be easily cracked.

Additionally, you could also log the MAC address of each device that supplies an incorrect password.  This is outside the scope of the post, but if you're interested, blacklisting what we'd assume to be the neighbors devices is also a possibility.

Comment: "The router only "broadcasts" a single network". That's not true. Many routers have a guest network, a 2.4ghz network, and a 5ghz network. All can have separate SSIDs.

Comment: That's true, especially in today's day and age.  I said it solely to simplify the answer.  It seemed he meant whether or not the neighbors could still connect to "their" network even after he reset it.  What I meant to allude to, was that it takes multiple antennaes/networking cards to broadcast multiple IDs.  It sounds like his station only broadcasts a single SSID, ergo, only a single network.  There is no "secret" network his neighbors can connect to running off of his router.